# Mediawiki 1.16: Template documentation example usage

Tags: mediawiki

I'm writing template documentation for a wiki and wanted to include a working example of the template. However, I wrote the template to auto-categorize various fields and the entire template itself is also auto-categorized.

This means if I simply call on the template, it will categorize the doc page...and because the actual template page transcludes the doc page, the template page will also be categorized.

Is there a way to prevent these categories from automatically kicking in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick. Wrap the categorization in your template inside a parserfunction:

```
{{#ifeq: {{NAMESPACE}} | Help || [[Category:Some_Category]] }}
```

This sets the category when the template is transcluded onto a page that is not in the "Help" namespace.

Comment: Namespace checking is a good idea. I didn't know we could do that so easily.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to allow a parameter such as `demo` to avoid including the category.

If you don't mind being slightly cryptic, you could do the category in the template as `{{{cat|[[Category:Some_Category]]}}}`; then specifying the parameter as `{{my template|cat=}}` will prevent the category inclusion.

Comment: That works, though in general additional arguments probably would get a little confusing for the general user (unless, of course, I don't mention it in the template!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question completely (what is "auto-categorize various fields"?). I am assuming here that you want to show a template "in action" on a documentation page - without attaching some categories (those categories the documentation page usually attaches to articles using this template) to the documentation page.

So

<onlyinclude>[[Category:Some_Category]]</onlyinclude>

will not do the job - as the template *is* in fact included. Right?

Try passing a parameter categorize=false to the template to indicate that categories are not to be attached in this case:

{{#ifeq:{{{categorize|}}}|false||[[Category:Some_Category]]}}

The double pipe after "false" means: if(categorize==false) then (empty), else [[Category:Some_Category]] - i.e. it is an equivalent construction for if(NOT(categorize==false))...

Good luck and thanks for all the fish,
Achim